# ES modules and jsconfig.json: Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I got a node web app project that uses regular JS.

I am trying to set some paths using a `jsconfig.json`. I tried using node default's [`Subpath imports`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/all.html#packages_subpath_imports) and even thou it does work, the vscode intellisense stopped working.

I found out you could use `jsconfig.json` so I set this file

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@controllers/*": ["node/controllers/*"],
    },
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

And on my `package.json` I added

```json
"type": "module",
```

My folder structure is

```
├── node
│    └──controllers
│         └── foo.js
├── server.js
├── jsconfig.json
└── package.json
```

But when I try to import from `server.js`

```js
import { foo } from '@controllers/foo.js'
// or import { foo } from '@controllers/foo'
```

`foo.js`

```
export const foo = 'Hello server'
```

I get

```
node:internal/process/esm_loader:74
     internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@controllers/foo.js' imported from /Users/Alvaro/Sites/test/server.js

 at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:363:5)
 at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:698:9)
 at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:739:18)
 at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:853:11)
 at Loader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:89:40)
 at Loader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:242:28)
 at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:73:40)
at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:72:36) {
code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
```

Comment: change `baseUrl:"."` to `baseUrl:"./"`

Comment: @SachinAnanthakumar, It does not fix it.

Comment: did you add a `export default` in foo.js ?

Comment: Yes of course, export default....

Comment: I am not sure why it doesn't work, is that the complete error stack trace?

Comment: I have changed the code and added the whole error stack

Comment: can you remove `module:commonjs` from  `compilerOptions` or  can you change the folder name from `node` to anything else, the visual studio docs say the common mapping for` node_modules` are called `node`

Comment: Nothing, did both, same results

Comment: Are you doing `default export` on `foo.js`, if yes don't import it as a `named export function` use `import Foo from './path'` instead

Comment: Read the question again, I have changed all that

Comment: can you push this repo with the error and give a link to repo?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237639/discussion-between-sachin-ananthakumar-and-alvaro).

Answer (score 5):

After hours of research, I have found that it is very difficult to have a custom alias path while using `esm` and very easily configured for  `commonjs`,

but it can be achieved, in a slightly different manner when you use `esm`,
I will write the solution for `esm` implementation in **method 1** and then for `commonjs` in  **method 2**

**Method 1**

**Step 0:**

remove `jsconfig.json`

**Step 1:**

in your `package.json` add an `exports` property,

```
"name": "package-name"

"exports":{
   "./@controllers/" : "./node/controllers/"
}
```

**Note:** Don't forget the '/' after the `@controllers` and `/node/controllers/`

**Step 2**

you will have to import the file

```
  import {foo} from "package-name/controllers/index.js" 
/*
package-name is the same value as the 'name' property in
the package.json
*/
```

to learn more about `exports` property in `package.json` refer [here](https://nodejs.org/dist./v12.12.0/docs/api/esm.html)

------------------------------XXXXXXXX----------------------------------

**Method 2**

you can't use `es modules` in this method

**Step 0**

install `module-alias` package.

`npm i module-alias`

remove `type:module` if it exists in `package.json` or change the value to `commonjs`;

**Step 1**

Add the below code at the starting line of the file which is specified as the **`entry point`** in `package.json`

`require(module-alias/register)`

check the `main` property in `package.json` in the **author's case** it should be `server.js`.

in `package.json` add this

```
"_moduleAliases": {
  "@root" : ".", // Don't forget to mnetion this
  "@controllers" : "node/controllers/*"
}
```

Now you can require modules from directries like below

```
const {foo} = require("@controllers/foo.js") // if foo is named export 

//or

const foo = require("@controllers/foo.js");
```

you can refer more about `module-alias` library [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias)

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I did mention node exports paths with the link above on the question to Subpath imports. The problem with it as I also mention on the question is that you will loose on Vscode the intellisense for functions that  are imported from those paths. It is all a pity as I not gonna give up on ES modules any time soon.

Comment: There isn't any solution available for node yet, hope they fix it, I will try to find some workaround today

Comment: method1 didn't work for me. I would still want to use es6 modules so I skipped method2.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, method 1 didn't work for me. But method 2 worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

What you have tried is almost correct.

you can get aliases working but it has to start with `#`.

for example: in `package.json`

```
"imports": {
    "#app": "./app.js"
}
```

and in `jsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "#app": ["./app.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) you can import your jsconfig.json file, iterate over its content, and create the alias programmatically.

In your entry file:

```
    const path = require("path");

    const moduleAlias = require("module-alias");
    const jsConfig = Object.entries(require("./jsconfig.json").compilerOptions.paths);

    for (let i = 0; i < jsConfig.length; i++) {
        const [key, val] = jsConfig[i];

        const k = key.replace("/*", "");
        const p = path.join(__dirname, val[0]).replace("/*", "");

        moduleAlias.addAlias(k, p);
    }
```

The value is `val[0]` because jsconfig defines each path as an array. Official example from the visualstudio website.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "ClientApp/*": ["./ClientApp/*"]
    }
  }
}
```